Inheritance and polymorphism in Python when using mypy not working
I'm looking to do some standard polymorphism with mypy, which I've never used before and it's so far not intuitive.
Base-class
class ContentPullOptions:
    pass


class Tool(Protocol):
    async def pull_content(self, opts: ContentPullOptions) -> str | Dict[str, Any]: ...

Sub-class
class GoogleSearchOptions(ContentPullOptions):
    query: str
    sites: List[str]


class GoogleSearchTool(Tool):
    async def pull_content(
        self,
        opts: GoogleSearchOptions,
    ) -> str | Dict[str, Any]:

Fails with:
error: Argument 1 of "pull_content" is incompatible with supertype "Tool"; supertype defines the argument type as "ContentPullOptions" 

What is the most maintainable and clean way to do basic inheritance with type checking in mypy like this?
I tried custom types, casting, etc. But everything felt a bit messy and unclear.
Solution
Maybe this still violates the Liskov Principle
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol, Dict, Any, List, Callable

# Define T as contravariant
T_contra = TypeVar('T_contra', bound=ContentPullOptions, contravariant=True)

class ContentPullOptions:
    pass

class Tool(Protocol[T_contra]):
    async def pull_content(self, opts: T_contra) -> str | Dict[str, Any]: ...

class GoogleSearchOptions(ContentPullOptions):
    query: str
    sites: List[str]

class GoogleSearchTool:
    async def pull_content(
        self,
        opts: GoogleSearchOptions,
    ) -> str | Dict[str, Any]:
        # Implementation here
        pass


Changing the argument type is a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle. An instance of GoogleSearchTool is still an instance of Tool, and Tool.pull_content still expects to take any instance of ContentPullOptions as an argument. (There are some subtitles regarding Protocol subclassing, though I think they are orthogonal to and irrelevant to the question at hand.)

@chepner Can you show an appropriate way to solve what I'm trying to do? I got something with Protocol subclassing to work, but not sure I'm following best practices here.

Like, do I need to just do explicit casting every time within the subclass override?

What you are doing is inappropriate in and of itself. You can't restrict the argument type(s) in inherited methods.

Just make the argument types match, either by limiting the scope of the superclass or widening the scope of the subclass.

Now, how to best pull fields that are specific to the subclasses type? For example, "query" or "sites" in the most mypythonic way

Your last snippet with typevar and protocol is fully correct and safe. I'd probably inherit from Tool[GoogleSearchOptions] explicitly - that isn't strictly necessary, but helps typechecker a bit and gives you more freedom since any non-conformance will be pointed out at definition site as opposed to use-site errors with implicit subtyping. Tiny nit: since you're using | for unions, you're at least 3.10+, so forget Dict and List and use their plain counterparts dict and list, which are parametrizeable since 3.9.

@STerliakov Thanks mate, that's helpful and makes sense

Don't add the solution to the question; post it as an answer.

What is the purpose of the ContentPullOptions base class if it doesn't actually provide any abstraction or data points?  The issue here is that the extending class has different data points and is therefore not compatible with the base class as per subtyping rules, so there isn't really a way to "fix" what you've done, except to remove the base class entirely.   There are hacks to stop mypy complaining..

Solution
Maybe this still violates the Liskov Principle
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol, Dict, Any, List, Callable

# Define T as contravariant
T_contra = TypeVar('T_contra', bound=ContentPullOptions, contravariant=True)

class ContentPullOptions:
    pass

class Tool(Protocol[T_contra]):
    async def pull_content(self, opts: T_contra) -> str | Dict[str, Any]: ...

class GoogleSearchOptions(ContentPullOptions):
    query: str
    sites: List[str]

class GoogleSearchTool:
    async def pull_content(
        self,
        opts: GoogleSearchOptions,
    ) -> str | Dict[str, Any]:
        # Implementation here
        pass


No, generic parametrization does not violate LSP, this solution is fine and often used in wild.

The type of an overridden method, in order to comply with the Liskov Substitution Principle, must be a subtype of the inherited method. Because functions are contravariant in their argument types, that means the overriden method's argument type must be a supertype of the inherited method's. That is, GoogleSearchTool.pull_content has to take an argument at least as general as ContentPullOptions, not something more specific.

so I have:
class GoogleSearchTool:
    async def pull_content(
        self,
        opts: ToolOptions,
    ) -> str | Dict[str, Any]:
        # Implementation here
        pass

Now I need query field since it's specific to this instance type, casting is the only solution?
